# Detection of a new fingerprint enrolment

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, biometrics

I’m currently working on Android Fingerprint implementation
https://github.com/googlesamples

and have a question regarding the code from the link:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/fingerprintdialog/MainActivity.java

My understanding of KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException is that it’s thrown when e.g. a fingerprint was deleted or a new fingerprint was added in the device settings. I’m getting that exception only if

1. open an app, the keys are created by mKeyGenerator.generateKey();
2. confirm a fingerprint
3. minimise the app
4. open settings and add a new fingerprint
5. come back to the app and try to authenticate again
6. a new KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException is thrown

However if the point 3 is replaced by “exit the app“ and I follow the next steps, the exception is not thrown for a simple reason that the keys are recreated. My question is how to detect whether a new fingerprint was added/deleted between 2 different runtimes?

Answer (score 1):

Move the keystore / fingerprint manager related code from onCreate to onResume.
You should load/check stuff again after returning to the app, and the easiest way to do this is to move them to onResume. On you r app start, the onResume will run too (onCreate -> onStart -> onResume), google for android activity licecycle for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My aim is to detect a fingerprint modification between runs of the app (even if the app is killed from the task manager)

Comment: Ah I see. I'm afraid that's not possible. There is no callback or broadcast about fingerprint registration changes, and Google's compatibility definition says (C-1-9 section): "MUST NOT enable 3rd-party applications to distinguish between individual fingerprints." So basically all you have is the FingerprintManager that can say the fingerprint you scan is registered or not, but that's it. See the (currently) latest compatibility definition here: https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf

Comment: let's give a chance the others, maybe there's some way to achieve though...